# How to extract values from nested dictionary variable in robot framework?

Tags: dictionary, nested, robotframework

I have nested dict variable and want to extract values from it to compare if it's equal to actual value. With keys it worked fine but then with nested dict I did not find a way of how to extract values (e.g. operatorid). Do you have any advice on how to do it?
Variable

```
${HIRING_DATA_TYPES}=    {'Job Profile': {"AND":"", "operatorId": 'in the selection list', "targetInstances": 'Finance'},
...    'Recruiter': {"AND":"", "operatorId": 'not in the selection list', "targetInstances": '3314 Tax'},'Job Requisition': {"AND":"", "operatorId": 'is not empty'},
...    'Description': {"AND":"", "operatorId": 'equal to', "dataType":"Text", "targetType": 'targetText', "targetValue": "SDET_text"},
...    'Description 2': {"AND":"", "operatorId": 'greater than', "dataType":"Text", "targetType": "targetText", "targetValue": "SDET_text"},
...    'Description 3': {"AND":"", "operatorId": 'greater than or equal to', "dataType":"Text", "targetType": "targetText", "targetValue": "SDET_text"}}
```

Extracting keys

```
Check Added Source Fields
    [Arguments]    ${RESPONSE}   ${FILTERS_TO_ADD}
    ${ACTUAL_SOURCE_FIELDS}=    Get Json Path    ${RESPONSE}    $.pipelines..filter..children..field..descriptor
    Sort list    ${ACTUAL_SOURCE_FIELDS}
    ${FILTERS_TO_ADD}=    Evaluate    ${HIRING_DATA_TYPES}
    ${EXPECTED_SOURCE_FIELDS}=    Get Dictionary Keys    ${FILTERS_TO_ADD}
    Lists Should Be Equal    ${ACTUAL_SOURCE_FIELDS}   ${EXPECTED_SOURCE_FIELDS}
```

Comment: You show creating a variable named `${HIRING_DATA_TYPES}` but you never use that variable in the code. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Also, I don't think `${HIRING_DATA_TYPES}` is a dictionary. It looks like a string based on how you've defined it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me in the following way:

```
Check Added Comp Operators and Values
    [Arguments]    ${RESPONSE}   ${FILTERS_TO_ADD}
    @{EXPECTED_COMP_OPERATOR}=    Create List
    FOR    ${key}    IN    @{HIRING_DATA_TYPES.keys()}
        ${COMP_OPER_VALUES}=    Get From Dictionary    ${HIRING_DATA_TYPES}[${key}]   operatorId
        Append To List    ${EXPECTED_COMP_OPERATOR}    ${COMP_OPER_VALUES}
    END
    Lists Should Be Equal    ${ACTUAL_COMP_OPER}    ${EXPECTED_COMP_OPERATOR}
```